# Twitter image sharing

Tags: php, twitter

How to share images in twitter using php? I know its using image upload api of twitter. But i have no idea how to implement this ? Please help to find a solution.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the Doc on twitter image sharing .

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update_with_media

Here's the only PHP library that supports twitter image uploads.

https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth

And Here's a working example of image sharing. With a couple edits your set.

```
<?php

 if ($_POST['message'] && $_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) 
        {
                require 'tmhOAuth.php';

                list($oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret) = explode('|', $GLOBALS['user']['password']);

                $tmhOAuth = new tmhOAuth(array(
                        'consumer_key'    => OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY,
                        'consumer_secret' => OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET,
                        'user_token'      => $oauth_token,
                        'user_secret'     => $oauth_token_secret,
                ));

                $image = "{$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']};type={$_FILES['image']['type']};filename={$_FILES['image']['name']}";

                $code = $tmhOAuth->request('POST', 'https://upload.twitter.com/1/statuses/update_with_media.json',
                                                                                          array(
                                                                                                 'media[]'  => "@{$image}",
                                                                                                 'status'   => " " . $status //A space is needed because twitter b0rks if first char is an @
                                                                                          ),
                                                                                          true, // use auth
                                                                                          true  // multipart
                                                                                );

                if ($code == 200) {
                        $json = json_decode($tmhOAuth->response['response']);

                        if ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") {
                                $image_url = $json->entities->media[0]->media_url_https;
                        }
                        else {
                                $image_url = $json->entities->media[0]->media_url;
                        }

                        $text = $json->text;

                        $content = "<p>Upload success. Image posted to Twitter.</p>
                                                        <p><img src=\"" . IMAGE_PROXY_URL . "x50/" . $image_url . "\" alt='' /></p>
                                                        <p>". twitter_parse_tags($text) . "</p>";

                } else {
                        $content = "Damn! Something went wrong. Sorry :-("  
                                ."<br /> code=" . $code
                                ."<br /> status=" . $status
                                ."<br /> image=" . $image
                                ."<br /> response=<pre>"
                                . print_r($tmhOAuth->response['response'], TRUE)
                                . "</pre><br /> info=<pre>"
                                . print_r($tmhOAuth->response['info'], TRUE)
                                . "</pre><br /> code=<pre>"
                                . print_r($tmhOAuth->response['code'], TRUE) . "</pre>";
                }
        } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you! This did work great with a little tweaking, but note that it will not work with the new Twitter API 1.1 endpoint.

Comment: UPDATE: Got it to work with API v.1.1, sorry for my previous comment, you need to change the endpoint url to https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update_with_media

Above link has all the necessary information I believe.

Answer (score 0):

There is one other library (it is forked) that can be used for image upload, see: [TwitterOauth](https://github.com/vsr/twitteroauth/commit/06306eb17c748bfff0215bc7580baf38360a78f0)

1. Download: [Oauth File](https://github.com/vsr/twitteroauth/blob/06306eb17c748bfff0215bc7580baf38360a78f0/twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php)
2. Use code:

```php
$path = '/absolute/path/to/background.jpg';
$meta = getimagesize($path);
$raw['image'] = $path.';type='.$meta['mime'];
$param['tile'] = 'true';
$status = $connection->post('account/update_profile_background_image',$param,$raw);
```

Answer (score -1):

Initially I got the same error when I simply provided the path of media file. Actually you need to provide the byte read. So set your media parameter as follows and it will work:

```
$filename = "image.jpg";
$handle = fopen($filename, "rb");
$image = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);


$params = array('media[]' => "{$image};type=image/jpeg;filename={$filename}" ,
            'status'   => 'my status');
$response =$twitteroauth->post('statuses/update_with_media', $params,true,true);
```

You can visit this link for complete reference http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-authenticate-users-with-twitter-oauth/